# Serving Cloudfront pages Through HTTP only

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a simple static site which I provide through Amazon's Cloudfront.  There is nothing of importance on there so it does not need HTTPS, furthermore I don't want to go through the hassle and cost of setting up an SSL certificate for my site, and I'm happy if requests are sent through HTTPS are met with a service unavailable or whatever other error message would be considered appropriate.  Instead, Cloudfront attempts to serve the HTTPS pages using its own certificate and so flags the site up in the browser as 'untrusted' due to the certificate/domain name mismatch.

Is there some way to disable HTTPS entirely in Cloudfront, or some other way of gracefully falling back to HTTP whilst still using Cloudfront?

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem.

Amazon now offers SSL certificates free of charge with following restrictions:

- You can only use them in CloudFront or ELB.
- Browsers which don't have *Server Name Indication* support won't render your site correctly.

In my case, I just used it even though I never need it. It is much better than having "Untrusted Connection" on the browser.

I couldn't find any mechanism to graceful fail or to block HTTPS completely.

See :  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html#CNAMEsAndHTTPS

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using AWS web console to setup their cloudfront, follow this path to change the "Viewer protocol policy":

AWS Web Console > Cloudfront > Cloudfront Distributions > [Select your distribution] > Behaviors tab > [Select your cache behavior] > Edit > Viewer Protocol Policy > Set "HTTP and HTTPS"

Answer (score 2):

You can specify independently, for each CloudFront origin, if it should use `HTTP` and `HTTPS` or only `HTTP` using the **Origin Protocol Policy** setting.

> **Protocols**
>
> CloudFront forwards HTTP or HTTPS requests to the origin server based
>   on the following:
>
> The protocol of the request that the end user sends to CloudFront,
>   either HTTP or HTTPS.
>
> The value of the **Origin Protocol Policy** field in the CloudFront
>   console or, if you're using the CloudFront API, the
>   `OriginProtocolPolicy` element in the `DistributionConfig` complex type.
>   In the CloudFront console, the options are **HTTP Only** and **Match Viewer**.
>
> If you specify **HTTP Only**, CloudFront forwards requests to the origin
>   server using only the HTTP protocol, regardless of the protocol in the
>   end-user request.

Source: [AWS CloudFront documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that is for requests between CloudFront and the origin rather than between the end user and CloudFront.

Comment: Sorry, I should have also mentioned that CloudFront will always make your content available trough both HTTP and HTTPS, but if you origin only supports HTTP, then you can simply set `Origin Protocol Policy` to `HTTP Only` and don't worry about HTTPS. You can not completely disable HTTPS on a CloudFront distribution (e.g. don't allow connections on port 443 on that distribution's hostname).

Comment: I'm using S3 as the origin so this option is not available.  Regardless, if as you state you cannot disable or otherwise reject attempted HTTPS connections then it appears I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Please notice that in case you wish to add an alternate domain name to a distribution:

It seems that since [this release](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-cloudfront-enhances-the-security-for-adding-alternate-domain-names-to-a-distribution/) (Apr 8, 2019) **when you add an alternate domain name to a distribution, you must also attach a SSL/TLS certificate to that distribution that covers the alternate domain name**.

So in that case you can't disable HTTPS.

---

(*) Note: I personally don't see the mentioned option of `HTTP Only` for Origin Protocol Policy - although it is also mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginProtocolPolicy).